# What is the relationship between Chirimoya fruit and cancer?

Tags: alternative-medicine

In the whole andes, there is a claim that chirimoya cures cancer.

This claim is supported long across the andes community, and in dubious [sites like this one](http://www.blogher.com/cancer-cure-anona-graviolachirimoya).

My question is: What is the actual extent -currently known- to the healing power of the chirimoya fruit? Has that fruit a proven* success against cancer in any way? (at least *helping* in any way with the healing of at least one form of cancer).

(*) *This should not need clarification but since this is my first question here I state: at least one study from a reputable laboratory proving some kind of success regarding any form of cancer*

Comment: I hope this dupemark become actually useful serving when people looks for the synonim *chirimoya*.

Comment: While similar I'm not so sure this should be called a dupe, Cherimoya/chirimoya is related to soursop but isn't the same plant. Unless we're just marking all generic claims that [plant] cures/prevents cancer as dupes.